# How to capture cancel events from inline editing

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How can I capture cancel events from a Kendo UI grid in inline editing. I have tried using the edit events to capture the cancel events, however it is not working. I am wondering if is there any way to do it.

```
.Events(ev => ev.Edit("onEdit"));
```

then I have the jQuery:

```
 $("tr .k-grid-cancel", "#Grid").on("click", function(e) {
        alert("cancel pressed!");
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the jQuery selector and when this is executed. When you do as you did you will intercept the events for those `tr` that had a CSS class `k-grid-cancel` that exist by the moment you execute it **but** you want to intercept DOM elements that will be created in the future. So you should do:

```
$("tr", "#Grid").on("click", ".k-grid-cancel", function(e) {
    alert("cancel pressed!");
});
```

Realize that I moved the `k-grid-cancel` to the [`jQuery.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). This is the current jQuery syntax for replacing old `live` function.